# Add a node specific counter to a slingly linked list

Tags: python-3.x

Did some research, but could only find examples where there was a key - say '5' and they count the occurrences of '5' in the linked list. I want to count each occurrence of each string in a llist. Say I have a linked list with ' a, a, a, b, d, f'. I want the output to say a - 3 b - 1 d -1 f -1.

I have built the list but the only way I can think of doing it is initializing a count variable, however I can't figure out how to reset it as I print the entire list after everything is done so right now my output looks like: a - 3 b -3 d -3 f -3.

Here is the code:

```
class Linked_List:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.count = 0

def print(self):
    p = self.head
    while p is not None:
        print(p.data, ' -', self.count)
        p = p.next

def insert(self, x):
    """"""
    p = self.head
    q = None
    done = False
    while not done:
        if self.head == x:
            done = True
        elif p == None:
            head = Linked_List_node(x)
            q.next = head
            done = True
        elif x == p.data:
            # head = Linked_List_node(x)

            # self.head = head
            self.count += 1
            done = True
        elif x < p.data:
            if self.head == p:
                head = Linked_List_node(x)
                head.next = p
                self.head = head
                done = True
            else:
                head = Linked_List_node(x)
                head.next = p
                q.next = head
                done = True
        q = p
        if p is not None:
            p = p.next
```

```
class Linked_List_node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.next = None
```

Revised Code:

```
    def print(self):
        p = self.head
        head = Linked_List_node(p.data)
        while p is not None:
            print(p.data, '-', self.count(p.data))
            p = p.next

    def count(self, x):
        # loop thru list for all x, if find x add 1 to count. Assign final count to that word.
        with open('cleaned_test.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                for word in line.split():
                    if word == x:
                        self.count += 1
```

Comment: Yes, please share the code you tried so far!

Comment: Aah the code is similar to what I answered for a previous question by you?

Comment: Yes :D I got it all working up to this counter thing... I can't seem to figure out how to make the numbers different.

Comment: Also I don't see your code for counting, please add that as well!

Comment: It's there, I initialized the count variable, and if the word being inserted into the list is = to a previous word, add one. (x == p.data). The only thing that's going on in the other file is iterating through a different text file filled with a list of words.

Comment: Consider writing a different function for counting, along similar lines of iterating through the list, and a hint, considering using a dictionary to keep track of counts of each letter

Comment: Great! Update the `count` function in the question if it works!

Comment: I'm getting an 'int' object is not callable error. I created count to loop thru the file, and then inside of the print function I want it to pass that specific word (before/while it prints) into count to count the iterations, and the insert function will delete duplicates in the output. The code is added onto the end of the question. I want to try to keep count as an attribute of the node, instead of using a dictionary.

Comment: Use a dictionary to keep count of individual elements to begin with, e.g. `{'a':1,'b':2}`, you can improve your logic accordingly!

Comment: Why doesn't this way work? (Sorry I didn't see your comment in time, so I posted the 'int' object not callable error again. ;-; Wouldn't it be easier just to pass in the word and iterate through the text file and count up the words?

Comment: You mention your output should look like `a - 3 b - 1 d -1 f -1`, which is what a dictionary is supposed to refer! So think about your code in that aspect, where you will update the count of each letter in that dictionary, Also Read up on python dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your `count` function to be able to count the frequencies of each word, I would create a function similar to `print` called `count` in class `Linked_List`, which iterates through the list, and updates the frequency dictionary.

```
def count(self):

    dct = {}
    p = self.head
    while p is not None:
        if p.data in dct:
            dct[p.data] += 1
        else:
            dct[p.data] = 1
        p = p.next
    return dct
```

The output will look like.

```
head = Linked_List_node('a')
ll = Linked_List()
ll.head = head
for item in ['a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'f']:
    ll.insert(item)
print(ll.count())
#{'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1}
```